# Wasabi coinjoin problem

Tags: coinjoin, wasabi-wallet

I used some coinjoined BTC coins from my from my WASABI wallet to exchange for ADA on Godex. I sent coins from Wasabi wallet but had Godex deposit them in my Exodus wallet. It was around 500€.

There was no problem with the exchange with Godex but all the other BTC coins in my wallet that were coinjoined were sent to Blockchain and remain there unconfirmed. I did not send them. The coins are gone from my wallet but I can see them on the blockchain.

All these coins in my Wasabi wallet were not conjoined together and the same time.
They were sent in 7 separate transactions from my Exodus wallet to separate addresses in my Wasabi wallet and then coinjoined separately. Now all these separate coinjoin coins are listed as an INPUTS on the blockchain. Unconfirmed

The BTC coins seen on Blockchain are are Unconfirmed and UNspent

HOW DO I GET  THEM BACK IN MY WASABI WALLET?

Comment: When you write "on Blockchain", do you mean 1) seen in any blockchain explorer. 2) Seen in a custodial account on exchange.blockchain.com. 3) something else?  Are you using a coinjoin feature built into the Wasabi wallet.

Comment: Seen in blockchain explorer

Comment: I used coinjoin feature built into Wasabi